# A different way of solving differentiability of a function

Tags: derivatives

Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
 (x-2)\cos(\frac{1}{x-2}),  & \text{if $x\neq$   0} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x$=0}
\end{cases}$$
And we have to check for the differentiability at the points $x=0$ and $x=2$.

We can easily check the differentiability by using the formula 
$f '(a)=\lim\limits_{h \to a} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} $ 
and surely the answer checks out the $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$ but not at $x=2$.

But instead of solving for the whole function, I went up to solve it in a different way, I checked the differentiability of the $f(x)=x-2$ at the points $x=0$ and $x=2$ and turned out that the function is differentiable at both the points. 
So, I tried a new trick here, that if there are two different function in multiplication
     ( $h(x)= f(x)\cdot g(x)$ ) 
such that $f(x)$ is differentiable at a point $x=a$, then surely the whole function( $h(x)= f(x)\cdot g(x)$ ) is differentiable at the point $x=a$.

This seems to work for other functions such as checking the differentiability of $f(x)=x|x|$ at $x=0$.
I am not sure why it is not working in the first one.

Comment: I think for your result to be true, in addition to $f(x)$ being differentiable at $x=a$, the function $g(x)$ should be continuous at $x=a$ as well.

Comment: Actually your function $f$ is not differentiable (it's not even continuous) at $x=0$ and is not defined at $x=2$.